# Get the posts count in JS (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have site on WP.

I'm using AJAX to show my posts. On click on 'more' button appears two more posts. And I'm trying to hide the button when all of the posts are shown. But something go wrong.

I don't understand how to take posts count to JS (it's another variant), because construction `var posts_count = "<?php echo $posts_count; ?>` doesn't work - it gives only string!

**JS**

```
$(function () {

  var posts = 2; //posts shown
  var posts_offset = 2;



  $("#load-post").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();


    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
      data: ({
        action: 'loadMore',
        posts_offset: posts_offset
      }),
      success: function (data) {
        $('.news #content').append(data);
        posts_offset += 2;

      }
    });


  });


});
```

**PHP**

```
function loadMore() {



    $posts_count = wp_count_posts()->publish; 

    $posts_offset = $_GET['posts_offset'];


    // get your $_GET variables sorted out

    // setup your query to get what you want
    query_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'offset'=> $posts_offset ) );

    // initialsise your output
    $output = '';

    // the Loop
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

         ?><div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 news-item">
              <div class="news-date">
                <?php the_time($format = "j F Y") ?>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h3><?php the_title() ?></h3>
                <p><?php the_content() ?></p>
              </div>
            </div><?php

    endwhile;

  if ($posts_count - ($posts_offset + 2) <= 0) { ?>
      <script>$("#load-more").hide();</script>
    <?php }


    // Reset Query
    wp_reset_query();

    die($output);

}
```

This code works, but doesn't work the part of hiding the button

Comment: You are not echo-ing the script part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code as follows:

in `PHP`

```
<script>function hideLoadMore(){$("#load-more").hide();}</script>
```

and in `JS`

```
success: function (data) {
    $('.news #content').append(data);
    posts_offset += 2;
    if(hideLoadMore) { 
        hideLoadMore(); 
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is your button id "load-more" or "load-post", which one you want to hide?

Comment: as the click event is on "load-post" not "load-more"

Answer (score 1):

You are not `echo` ing the script part.

```
if ($posts_count - ($posts_offset + 2) <= 0) {
      echo '<script>$("#load-more").hide();</script>';
}
```

And why you are not separating the javascript part from php? Would be more elegant if you handle the scripting logic from ajax. In php you are sending back some response if the condition is not met, then you handle the DOM manipulation from javascript.

Comment: It doesn't work for me( what about more elegant solution - I have a little expirience of PHP, so I don't know how to make it